# Test a form with FormControl input

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-components, angular-forms

So I have a component like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'bg-formfield-markdown',
    host: {
        class: 'forminput',
        '[class.forminput-is-error]': 'isErrorState',
        '[class.forminput-locked]': 'isLockedState',
    },
    template: `<md-editor (ngModelChange)="change()" [(ngModel)]="markdown_content" [upload]="doUpload"></md-editor>`,
    styleUrls: ['./formfield-markdown.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class FormFieldMarkdown implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
```

in there, I pass a `FormControl` as `@Input`, like this:

```
@Input() control: FormControl;
```

I can then use this in other components like this:

```html
<bg-formfield-markdown
    class="l-formsection-x-inputoffset"
    [control]="issueForm.rawControlMap.narrative"
    label="How did the recipient earn this badge?">
</bg-formfield-markdown>
```

In my Unit Test I configure the testing module like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
      FormFieldMarkdown,
      BgMarkdownComponent,
      MarkdownHintsDialog
  ],
  imports: [
      RouterTestingModule,
      CommonModule,
      ...COMMON_IMPORTS,
  ],
  providers: [
      ...COMMON_MOCKS_PROVIDERS_WITH_SUBS,
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
}).compileComponents();
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormFieldMarkdown);
fixture.componentInstance.control = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
fixture.detectChanges();
component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
```

This, however, fails with the following error message:

```
Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control unspecified name attribute. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01203

error properties: Object({ code: -1203 })
    at _throwMissingValueAccessorError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:180376:9)
    at setUpControl (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:180158:29)
    at NgModel._setUpStandalone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:181307:5)
    at NgModel._setUpControl (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:181295:33)
    at NgModel.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:181254:12)
    at NgModel.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:142324:10)
    at callHookInternal (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:143324:10)
    at callHook (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:143351:5)
    at callHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:143308:9)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:143262:5)
```

I (and also [others](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43821)) find this error message extremely unhelpful and can't really figure out what's going wrong. I tried adding a provider as described [here](https://angular.io/errors/NG01203) to the `TestBed` configuration, as well as the component itself. However, I don't really know what the `forwardRef` should refer to; `FormControl`, `FormFieldMarkdown`, or another component altogether? The things I tried all didn't work, anyways.
I also tried importing some other components and stuff, that didn't help either.

Also, this unit test *should* have worked some while ago, before we upgraded Angular. The whole project is [open source](https://github.com/mint-o-badges/badgr-ui/tree/ui_get_tests_to_run), so feel free to check out the code for more context. I don't feel able to create a minimal example or anything of that kind, because I'm not familiar with Angular at all (and I feel like this is probably an easy fix for someone who *is* familiar with it).

Comment: Are you using bg-formfield-markdown inside a reactive form?

Comment: @TalhaAkca I'm not entirely sure, [but it seems so](https://github.com/mint-o-badges/badgr-ui/blob/ui_get_tests_to_run/src/app/issuer/components/badgeclass-issue/badgeclass-issue.component.html#L110).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end it didn't have anything to do with the `FormControl` at all - I just misunderstood the error message in that regard. The problem was that my component used [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown-editor) markdown editor. The necessary module was properly imported in my general module, but not in my test. I thus fixed it by importing the `LMarkdownEditorModule` in my `TestBed` configuration and adding the necessary scripts, assets and imports. See [this commit](https://github.com/mint-o-badges/badgr-ui/commit/a18184ac782efdc132a2cdd32fa04264c7e5a92d) for details; I don't think it's too relevant, since it has nothing to do with what I originally asked for in this question.

Maybe the learning for someone randomly stumbling upon this could be that you shouldn't try to get *any* information from this error message, but rather just try to produce a minimal example producing the error in order to debug it.